# matplotlib invalid RGBA argument - assign list of colours works for bar plot but not for line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use a custom colormap for matplotlib but getting the error
`ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: [(0.12156862745098039, 0.4666666666666667, 0.7058823529411765),...`

It annoyingly works for a bar plot, but not for a line plot.

My absolute minimum example:

`plt.bar(range(10), range(10), color=tableau20)`

[image: example_1]

My failing example (actual example as more lines):

`plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 10), color=tableau20)`

My colormap is as follows:

```
tableau20 = [(0.12156862745098039, 0.4666666666666667, 0.7058823529411765),
 (0.6823529411764706, 0.7803921568627451, 0.9098039215686274),
 (1.0, 0.4980392156862745, 0.054901960784313725),
 (1.0, 0.7333333333333333, 0.47058823529411764),
 (0.17254901960784313, 0.6274509803921569, 0.17254901960784313),
 (0.596078431372549, 0.8745098039215686, 0.5411764705882353),
 (0.8392156862745098, 0.15294117647058825, 0.1568627450980392),
 (1.0, 0.596078431372549, 0.5882352941176471),
 (0.5803921568627451, 0.403921568627451, 0.7411764705882353),
 (0.7725490196078432, 0.6901960784313725, 0.8352941176470589),
 (0.5490196078431373, 0.33725490196078434, 0.29411764705882354),
 (0.7686274509803922, 0.611764705882353, 0.5803921568627451),
 (0.8901960784313725, 0.4666666666666667, 0.7607843137254902),
 (0.9686274509803922, 0.7137254901960784, 0.8235294117647058),
 (0.4980392156862745, 0.4980392156862745, 0.4980392156862745),
 (0.7803921568627451, 0.7803921568627451, 0.7803921568627451),
 (0.7372549019607844, 0.7411764705882353, 0.13333333333333333),
 (0.8588235294117647, 0.8588235294117647, 0.5529411764705883),
 (0.09019607843137255, 0.7450980392156863, 0.8117647058823529),
 (0.6196078431372549, 0.8549019607843137, 0.8980392156862745)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the `pyplot.bar`, `plot` does not accept a list of colors for `color`, so you will have to decide for each line which color it will be. The following example uses your color number 6:

```
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 10), color=tableau20[6])
```

Output:

[image]